# What's the meaning of [0] in this line of code?

Tags: python, string, input, slice

I'm learning Python, and I wanted to do a simple yes/no question.

I stumbled with this code on the internet:

```
qr = input('Do you love cute owls?')
while True:
    if qr == '' or not qr[0].lower() in ['y','n']: # This line in question
        print('Please answer with yes or no!')
    else:
        break

if qr[0].lower() == 'y': #Do something
if qr[0].lower() == 'n': #Do something else
```

and this allows the code to detect any word starting with y or n, so it looks more "smart".

I really want to know whats the difference between that code and just writing:

```
qr = input('Do you love cute owls?')
while True:
    if qr == '' or not qr.lower() in ['y','n']: # Difference
        print('Please answer with yes or no!')
    else:
        break

if qr.lower() == 'y': #Do something
if qr.lower() == 'n': #Do something else
```

Why the second code doesn't work? What's the purpose of that `[0]` and why without it the code doesn't detect the words starting with `y` or `n`? I really want to know! :)

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: `some_string[0]` gives you the first character of the string.

Comment: Do you want to treat 'yes', 'yeah', etc. as 'y'? If so, you should look only at the first letter of the input (which is `qr[0]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Referring to this line: `if qr == '' or not qr[0].lower() in ['y','n']:`

The `[0]` on `qr` refers to the *first* character of the input `qr` only.

(2) The differences between this two pieces of code is on the same one, the first is

- `if qr == '' or not qr[0].lower() in ['y','n']:`
- `if qr == '' or not qr.lower() in ['y','n']:`

The second one affects the *entire string* of `qr` and keeps all the characters, and makes a difference if you input a string longer than one character.